# Host Multiple Golang Sites on One IP and Serve Depending on Domain Request?

Tags: http, nginx, go, port

I'm running a VPS with Ubuntu installed. How can I use the same VPS (same IP) to serve multiple Golang websites without specifying the port (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084) in the url?

For example, **Golang app 1 is listening on port 8084** and **Golang app 2 is listening on port 8060**. I want Golang app 1 to be served when someone requests from domain `example1.com` and Golang app 2 to be served when someone requests from domain `example2.com`.

I'm sure you can do this with Nginx but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try out the following code,

```
server {
   ...
   server_name www.example1.com example1.com;
   ...
   location / {
      proxy_pass app_ip:8084;
   }
   ...
}

...

server {
   ...
   server_name www.example2.com example2.com;
   ...
   location / {
      proxy_pass app_ip:8060;
   }
   ...
}
```

app_ip is the ip of the machine wherever same is hosted, if on the same machine, put `http://127.0.0.1` or `http://localhost`

Comment: This is for Nginx?

Comment: Yes sir, it is for nginx,

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm just setting it up and I'll try it out now!

Comment: Roger that sir,

Comment: For every site, should I declare a new `server {}` or just have 1 `server {}` managing all my go-sites?

Comment: Depends on you, but it is better to do it this way, even debugging gets easier, so yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125426/discussion-between-acidic-and-satys).

Answer (score 12):

Nginx free solution.

First of all you can redirect [connections on port 80 as a normal user](https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-to-run-a-server-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user-on-linux)

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8000
sudo netfilter-persistent save
sudo netfilter-persistent reload
```

Then use [gorilla/mux](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux) or similar to create a route for every host and even get a "subrouter" from it

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
s := r.Host("www.example.com").Subrouter()
```

So the complete solution would be

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "fmt"
)

func Example1IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello www.example1.com!") // send data to client side
}

func Example2IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello www.example2.com!") // send data to client side
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    s1 := r.Host("www.example1.com").Subrouter()
    s2 := r.Host("www.example2.com").Subrouter()

    s1.HandleFunc("/", Example1IndexHandler)
    s2.HandleFunc("/", Example2IndexHandler)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Comment: I see how this could work but having several websites to host, this method could be a little messy.

Comment: It is entirely depends on architecture design. Look at [microservices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) for instance. I don't say reverse proxy is a bad idea, just more options to consider.

Answer (score 4):

You don’t need any third party routers. Simply create a host switch that implements *http.Handler* interface.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type HostSwitch map[string]http.Handler

// Implement the ServerHTTP method
func (hs HostSwitch) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if handler, ok := hs[r.Host]; ok && handler != nil {
        handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    } else {
        http.Error(w, "Forbidden", http.StatusForbidden)
    }
}
```

I hope this gives you the idea. If you need full code example https://play.golang.org/p/bMbKPGE7LhT

You can also read more about it on [my blog](https://rafallorenz.com/go/go-multidomain-host-switch/)

Comment: thanks this solution, had been looking for something which uses go instead of nginx or apache.