# Is it possible to handle multi domains in Golang?

Tags: http, go, dns, webserver

I want to handle multi-domains with Golang.

Like this , If browser sends request for http://sampledomain.me handles it with specific Golang program ,

In other cases , I want many programs on one server and tell each one of them , to handle each domain.

All programs are listening on 80 and many domains point to one server.

Can anybody help me ?

Thx...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Go programs can't all listen on port 80. You'd need something in front, like [nginx](http://nginx.org/), to act as a reverse proxy. The following nginx config excerpt would forward two domains on to two different programs, each listening on different ports:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domain1.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host            $host;
                proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        }

}  

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domain2.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host            $host;
                proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        }

}
```

Comment: Great ! That was what I want !

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need anything in front, like nginx,
although in some cases it is recommended.

Please find similar answer here "[Host Multiple Golang Sites on One IP and Serve Depending on Domain Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39894171/host-multiple-golang-sites-on-one-ip-and-serve-depending-on-domain-request)"

Answer (score 1):

I use both but Prefer second solution the most :

1. nginx as proxy having multiple Golang app on multiple port
   i.e. GoApp1:8081 GoApp2:8082 GoApp3:8083 ....

   server {
          ...
          server_name www.example1.com example1.com;
          ...
          location / {
             proxy_pass app_ip:8081;
          }
          ...
       }
       server {
          ...
          server_name www.example2.com example2.com;
          ...
          location / {
             proxy_pass app_ip:8082;
          }
          ...
       }
       .
       .
       .
2. nginx as proxy having multiple Golang app on same port(8081)
   separating by(Golang) func (u *URL) Hostname() string

   server {
      ...
      server_name www.example1.com example1.com;
      ...
      location / {
         proxy_pass app_ip:8081;
      }
      ...
   }

There is another way around(without nginx):
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8081
sudo netfilter-persistent save
sudo netfilter-persistent reload
```